# It's time to update the theme of stackexchange.com - the old beta theme currently used looks outdated

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, stackexchange.com

On Mar 17, the new design for beta sites was rolled out, in accordance to other LESS designs.

However, not only the beta sites had that beta theme - http://stackexchange.com have the design, *very* much similar (if not exactly the same) to the old beta design, which looks a bit outdated - same footer&header, badge icons, buttons styling, etc.

Any plans to update it? If not, I think it is time to do it - upgrade to the new LESSy design.

Comment: Maybe... once all beta sites are updated and area51... 6 - 8 something...

Comment: @rene Wait, what do you mean by all beta sites? They have one new design currently...

Comment: I mean all the current design backlog...

Comment: @rene Ah, you mean the sites waiting for an update... Clear now.

Comment: Can't say that I notice what themes are present, I tend to focus on the content.

Comment: Sorry, really can't see any beta theme on stackexchange.com - it  got its own unique design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard proudly said:

> Sorry, really can't see any beta theme on stackexchange.com - it got its own unique design.

Meta Stack Exchange has a separate theme from all the rest of the sites. It is really not a beta but a "combination" of all the sites thus with all the hot questions, users, etc. Sure the top seems kinda plain but there's nothing wrong with that. This is not a site decorating contest. I mean not a lot of people are going to leave the site due to the site looking "plain and old".

The site looks nice I have to say. All the attention is at the contents not the decorations. So I say, no updates!

Comment: The thing I can't get is why "proudly" :D